# Polynomial ring with division in some variables

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, sagemath

While reading a textbook I have encountered a Polynomial Ring with notation R(x1,x2...xm)[y1,y2...yn]. This is a ring that includes all polynomial with xs and ys in the numerator and xs in the denominator. Is there a canonical name for such a ring? I would like to work over this ring in a Sagemath script, is there a way to implement this (e.g take the union of a Polynomial Ring and a Laurent Ring)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what the notation represents, but I was finally able to implement this as a Polynomial Ring in variables y1..yn over the Fraction Field of variables x1..xm

Comment: Yes, this is what the notation represents. You can accept your own answer to mark the question as solved.